# ToshortDateString() and CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.6

I want to convert persia date to Gregorian Date. I use this code.

```
public static void GetDate()
 {
String persianDate="1384/03/15"
Datetime dt= GetComponentDate(persianDate);
 }

 DateTime GetComponentDate(string fdate)
{
    DateTime edate;
    int year = int.Parse(Persia.Number.ConvertToLatin(fdate.Split('/')[0]));
    int month = int.Parse(Persia.Number.ConvertToLatin(fdate.Split('/')[1]));
    int day = int.Parse(Persia.Number.ConvertToLatin(fdate.Split('/')[2]));
    try
    {
        System.Globalization.PersianCalendar x = new System.Globalization.PersianCalendar();
        DateTime dt = x.ToDateTime(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        return dt;

    }
    catch
    {
    }
    return DateTime.MinValue;
}
```

In a server this method is runnig good and output is "17/6/2017" . but in a another server this method not work and output="15/03/1384" and I have to use this code after GetComponentDate is used.

```
((DateTime)dt).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

what is different in two servers?
can you help me?

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Can you **also** give some sample input and the associated output of calls to `GetComponentDate`?

Comment: What is `Persia.DateType.Gregorian`? Calling `ToString` shouldn't do anything on its own as a statement... what is `dt`? There's a lot of information missing here at the moment.

Comment: I updated my code. in a server I can convert persian date when I use  method GetComponentDate only but in another server I shoud use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture when I want concert date to String. what is different in two servers?

Comment: What is `Persia` & `Persia.Number`?  You need to provide us with a [mcve]. We need to be able to run your code.

Comment: It's still not clear what's wrong - I suspect it has nothing to do with the code you've shown us. If you hard-code a `DateTime` value (instead of using that code) do you see the same result? (Note that catching all exceptions like this is a pretty ugly way of handling invalid input, but that's a different matter.) I strongly suspect that one of your servers is using a default culture which uses a non-Gregorian calendar system, and the other isn't. If you want a specific format using a specific calendar, it's entirely reasonable to specify the culture...

Comment: For diagnostics purposes, I suggest you print out `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` - I'm sure that will show you the difference between the two machines...

Comment: @FatemeJafari - Please, we need a [mcve]. Your code should copy-paste-and-run for us.

Answer (score 0):

You say you need to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` in order to make it work on both servers, and then you ask "what is different in two servers".

I'd say what is different is the **culture**.

You can set your app culture by adding the globalization line in your web.config :

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <globalization uiCulture="[uiculture]" culture="[culture]" />
```

Replace `[uiculture]` and `[culture]` with accurate values.

E.g for US culture :

```
<globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US"/>
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx) is a list of all different cultures.

Comment: why in first server I don't use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture and code is running good? how can I set culture in server?

Comment: I searched a lot. I use <globalization culture=""/> in webconfig but It is not effect in .ascx page also I wrote Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture in Gloabal.ascx but This is not work too

Comment: where can I compare cultutre in two servers?

Comment: I tested both of them.but it does not any effect

Comment: @FatemeJafari Can you copy/paste the exact line you inserted in your web.config ?

Comment: excusme what is accurate values? I don't know. I know culture is different but I don't know where can I see sever's culture

Comment: I wrote  <globalization culture="" uiCulture=""/> in webconfig

Comment: @FatemeJafari What you want to do in your web.config is set the default culture of your app regardless of the server's culture. See my edit for more info.

Comment: I want to use  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture default in web config. I copy/past my code (<globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US"/>) but not effect in out put! output is "15/03/1384"

Comment: @FatemeJafari did you put this line at the right place ? (I edited my answer again) Also is your output still different between servers or does it output "15/03/1384" on both servers ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146933/discussion-between-rafalon-and-fateme-jafari).

Comment: please see my chat